# Is there a way to programmatically access sms's from a computer?

Tags: java, sms, command-line-interface

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [How to do interactive SMS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4366659/how-to-do-interactive-sms)
>   [How to send SMS in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2570410/how-to-send-sms)

I am trying to create a program that will allow you to text a phrase to a number, and then have the computer interpret that phrase and send something back.
Originally I thought I could use google voice, but I haven't been able to find a way to download incoming text messages.

How to get text messages on a computer?
Java is preferred.

Comment: I agree that the answer is probably in that question; I certainly good some good information from it. +1, Greg

Answer (score 1):

Twilio (where I work) has a [Java helper](http://www.twilio.com/docs/libraries/) and sending/receiving SMS is just a [series of HTTP POST requests](http://www.twilio.com/sms/).

Answer (score 0):

There is an Open Source library `SMSLib`, by using this library can send and read SMS from a compatible mobile connected via Bluetooth/Serial Port

- v4: https://github.com/tdelenikas/smslib
- v3: https://github.com/tdelenikas/smslib-v3