# Triggering USSD menu on receiving sms

Tags: ussd

Is there any way to send USSD menu on receiving sms from user mobile?.

When i am search in google i got following reference

https://github.com/Mobicents/ussdgateway

My question is

Whether i need to buy any api from mobile operator for sending USSD menu? or the software from mobicents is enough for delivering USSD menu. I know network operator support needed when i am dialing any USSD code like *123# to get USSD menu. here i am planning to send USSD menu on receiving sms form user mobile.

Comment: No one seems to have addressed this part that if its possible to send a USSD menu on a USSD PUSH, its possible on a USSD PULL i.e. user initiated, but is it possible on Network Initiated (USSD PUSH)

Answer (score 0):

A similar question has already been asked and answered on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4366659/how-to-do-interactive-sms). Though the solution is for C#, it can be easily replicated on other platforms too.

Some help could be found on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2902729/java-ussd-menu-tree-generation-how-to) too.

If you could provide more information, like target geography, type of service - then you might get better help.

Answer (score 0):

You will need an USSD Gateway (i.e: above mobicents ussdgw) to interrogate with the HLRs of mobile operators.

In your case, the USSDGW must have USSD terminating features to push push ussd menu to mobile phone.

The procedure shall be:
1. Receive the sms, then you know the MSISDN and sms content which help to know which service was required.
2. Based on MSIDN, you will retrieve the mobile's IMSI from network
3. Push ussd menu to mobile IMSI network.

The ussdgw will do steps 2,3 for you.

Answer (score 0):

A lot of n/w components comes into picture.

1. You should have SMSC which can recieve the SMS from the user.
2. A application which will get this SMS and then wants to send a USSD Menu
3. A USSD Gateway capable of doing a USSD push.
4. The application after recieving the SMS, will have the MSC,IMSI,MSISDN of the subscriber
   and hence push the USSD menu for the same using USSD Gateway.